# Save data to database jquery ajax through repeater

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

Hello everyone I'm using a repeater to save my data to my database but I'm having a problem, the first button that is repeater is being trigger while the other not can someone help please?

Can you please check and then why the other button are not being trigger please thank for your support.

```
   <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Bidding.aspx.vb" Inherits="Bidding" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="SM1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

 
     <asp:repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
      <HeaderTemplate>
            <ul>
      </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>

          <li> <a href="ProductDetails.aspx?ItemID=<%# Eval("ItemID") %>"> <asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Image1") %>' /></a>
         
            <div class="product-info">
               <h3>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:Label> </h3>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <h4>Bid</h4>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtbid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:Button ID="btnSave"
                      runat="server" Text="btnSave" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" Value='<%#Eval("EndDate")%>' runat="server" />
                  <asp:Label ID="lblauction" Visible="false" Text='<%#Eval("AuctionID")%>' runat="server" />
                <strong class="price"><%# Eval("Price")%></strong>
                <br/> <p>
               
                    

                    <asp:UpdatePanel id="updPnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
                   
                <asp:Label ID="lblTimer"   runat="server"></asp:Label>
                     </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" EventName ="tick" />
                    </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                       </div>
                    
                    
                     </p>
                  
               </div>
                
            </div>
          </li>
          </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>
        
            </ul>
      </FooterTemplate>
     </asp:repeater>
        

       <asp:Timer ID="timer1" Interval="1000" OnTick="timer1_tick" runat ="server">
                   </asp:Timer>
        
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenItem" runat="server" />
        
    </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.1/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[id*=btnSave]").on("click", function () {
                var user = {};
                user.BiddingPrice = $("[id*=txtbid]").val();
                user.AuctionID = $("[id*=lblauction]").val();
                
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Bidding.aspx/SaveUser",
                    data: '{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("BID has been added successfully.");
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Web.Configuration
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Web.Services

Partial Class Bidding


    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("VirgoPlaza").ToString())
    Dim EndDate As DateTime
    Dim auction As Integer
    Private ReadOnly _start As String
    Public Sub New()
        _start = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("VirgoPlaza").ConnectionString
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

            Using con1 As New SqlConnection(_start)


                Dim sql1 As String = "SELECT Item.ItemID, Item.Name,Item.Image1, Item.Description, Item.Price,Auction.EndDate,Auction.AuctionID FROM Item INNER JOIN Auction ON Item.ItemID = Auction.ItemID Where Auction.Status='Valid' AND Auction.EndDate>=@endate "
                Dim myCommand1 As New SqlCommand(sql1, con1)
                myCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endate", DateTime.Now)

                myCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                con1.Open()

                Dim category As SqlDataReader
                category = myCommand1.ExecuteReader()

                'binding data from category table to ddlcategory
                Repeater1.DataSource = category
                Repeater1.DataBind()

            End Using
          
        End If
    End Sub

    <WebMethod()> _
    <ScriptMethod()> _
    Public Shared Sub SaveUser(ByVal user As BID)
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("VirgoPlaza").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd2 As New SqlCommand("Select BiddingPrice From Bid")
                cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                con.Open()
                cmd2.Connection = con
                Dim result As Double = cmd2.ExecuteScalar

                Dim result2 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(result)

                Dim con1 As New SqlConnection(constr)

                Dim auction1 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(user.AuctionID)
                If result2 = 0 Then
                    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO BID VALUES(@Date, @BiddingPrice,@Status,@AuctionID,@BuyerID)")
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BiddingPrice", User.BiddingPrice)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "Available")
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuctionID", auction1)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BuyerID", 1)

                        cmd.Connection = con
                        con.Open()
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        con.Close()
                    End Using
                Else
                    If result2 >= User.BiddingPrice Then

                        MsgBox("Bid should be greather")

                    Else

                        Dim finalbid As Double = result2
                        MsgBox(finalbid)
                        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE  BID  SET Date =@Date,BiddingPrice= @BiddingPrice,Status=@Status,AuctionID=@AuctionID,BuyerID =@BuyerID")
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BiddingPrice", User.BiddingPrice)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "Available")
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuctionID", 11)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BuyerID", 1)

                            cmd.Connection = con

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            con.Close()
                        End Using




                    End If


                End If


            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Class BID
        Public Property BiddingPrice As Integer
            Get
                Return _BiddingPrice

            End Get

            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _BiddingPrice = value

            End Set
        End Property
        Private _BiddingPrice As String
        Public Property AuctionID As Integer
            Get
                Return _AuctionID

            End Get

            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _AuctionID = value

            End Set
        End Property
        Private _AuctionID As String

        
    End Class

    Protected Sub timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles timer1.Tick


        For Each item As RepeaterItem In Repeater1.Items
           
            Dim hidden = TryCast(item.FindControl("HiddenField1"), HiddenField)
            If Not SM1.IsInAsyncPostBack Then
                hidden.Value = hidden.Value

            End If
            Dim label2 = TryCast(item.FindControl("lblTimer"), Label)
            'Grab your DateTime object (checking that it exists)'

            'Store your TimeSpan Difference'
            Dim ts = (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(hidden.Value))
            Dim travelTime As New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0)
            'Now you can output your time as you please (excluding any decimal points)'
            label2.Text = String.Format("Time Left: {0:dd\:hh\:mm\:ss}", ts)
            Dim result2 As Integer = TimeSpan.Compare(ts, travelTime)

            If result2 >= 0 Then
                Using con1 As New SqlConnection(_start)




                    Dim sql1 As String = "SELECT Item.ItemID FROM Item INNER JOIN Auction ON Item.ItemID = Auction.ItemID Where Auction.Status='Valid' AND Auction.EndDate<=@endate "
                    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql1, con1)
                    con1.Open()
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endate", DateTime.Now)
                    Dim query As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar
                    ''query = Convert.ToInt32(HiddenItem.Value).ToString look in finalcoursework
                    Response.Redirect("ShoppingCart.aspx?query=")
                    con1.Close()
                End Using
            End If

        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You're going to have to format your code.

Comment: how can u give an example please.. and where to format it